# How to get the number of devices connected to openwrt in realtime?

Tags: dhcp, openwrt

I tryed `cat /tmp/dhcp.leases | wc -l` but have a time delay.

Is there any way to get the number of devices in real time, including wired and wireless devices?

Comment: Define _"connected"_. What do you mean?

Comment: The device is connected to the LAN port of the router with a network cable. Or connect to the router by Wi-Fi.

Comment: There is an easy command for lan: `ethtool <port e.g. eth0>`. Wireless can't be detected exactly, because you never know if it's only idle and will send a packet in a second, or it has completely gone. You can tune timeouts for this problem, but it will be never accurate, because wifi is not a continous connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is 

`opkg update
opkg install arp-scan
arp-scan --interface=br-lan --localnet | grep responded | awk '{print $12}'`

it will return the number of devices which connected to OpenWRT by LAN port. Almost real time.